# Creating a new string using index

Tags: python, string, indexing

Doing a python problem and trying to create a new string that omits a single char at index n. This works:

```
newstr = str[:n] + str[n+1:]
```

but wondering why this didn't work:

```
newstr = str[:n] + str[-1:-(n+1)]
```

Thanks in advance^

Comment: Your slice limits are inverted.

Comment: For future posts, please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  "didnt' work" is not a problem specification, and your posted code doesn't run.